# Code Expire in CAS SSO Server

Tags: authentication, oauth, single-sign-on, cas

I deployed my CAS server with OAuth protocol support

I've added this code to my deployerConfigContext.xml

```
<bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegisteredServiceImpl">
    <property name="id" value="1"/>
    <property name="name" value="the_key"/>
    <property name="description" value="the_secret"/>
    <property name="theme" value="my great webapp for OAuth"/>
    <property name="serviceId" value="http://localhost:8080/cas/login"/>
    <property name="evaluationOrder" value="10000001"/>
    <property name="allowedAttributes">
        <list>
            <!-- facebook -->
            <value>the_key</value>
            <value>the_secret</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and

```
<bean id="ticketRegistry" class="org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="1000"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="1"/>
    <constructor-arg index="2" value="16"/>
</bean>
```

to define my ticketRegistry
So my OAuth client secret code key is the_secret and the_key

but when I load this URL `http://localhost:8080/cas/oauth2.0/accessToken?client_secret=the_secret&grant_type=refresh_token&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fcas%2Flogin&code=0&client_id=the_key` to test my OAuth protocol, I've got this exception

`<Code Expired 0>`

Why and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define two CAS services :

1. one for internal mechanism of OAuth server support (with CASservice.serviceId = `http://localhost:8080/cas/oauth2.0/callbackAuthorize`)
2. one for the each client OAuth application you want to authorize (with oauthclient.key = CASservice.name, oauthclient.secret = CASservice.description, oauthclient.redirect_uri should start with CASservice.serviceId).

The documentation : https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/OAuth+server+support, part 3...